# Pythonista 3 cannot recognize line breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline, pythonista

```
import sys

print(sys.stdin.readline())
```

```
1
2
3
```

When I run the code above with the values above on pythonista 3, it doesn’t recognize line breaks and the output appears as follows

```
1
2
3
```

I expected the result to be like below

```
1
```

But readline() didn’t recognize line break and get ‘1\n2\n3’

How can I solve this problem?